# store.dispatch cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

I am trying to test my `async` action and I get this error:

> store.dispatch cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I tried to use the `then` on the `actionTypes` (I am sorry, that is an `actionCreator` but I imported it as `actionType`), but it goes from `undefined` to:

> TypeError: actionTypes.fetchGitHubDataAsync(...).then is not a function.

```js
it('Dispatches BOOKS_SUCCESS after fetching books', () => {
   // Response body sample
   const mockData = [
   {
       "name": "javascript",
       "display_name": "JavaScript",
       "short_description": "JavaScript (JS) is a lightweight interpreted programming language with first-class functions.",
       "description": "JavaScript (JS) is a lightweight interpreted or JIT-compiled programming language with first-class functions. While it is most well-known as the scripting language for Web pages, many non-browser environments also use it, such as Node.js, Apache CouchDB and Adobe Acrobat. JavaScript is a prototype-based, multi-paradigm, dynamic language, supporting object-oriented, imperative, and declarative (e.g. functional programming) styles.",
       "created_by": "Brendan Eich",
       "released": "December 4, 1995",
       "created_at": "2016-11-28T18:41:00Z",
       "updated_at": "2019-11-06T15:05:24Z",
       "featured": true,
       "curated": true,
       "score": 7954.724
   }
   ]

   fetchMock.getOnce('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript',
                { body: { results: mockData }})

   const expectedActions = [
         { type: actionTypes.FETCH_GITHUB_DATA},
   ]
   store.dispatch(actionTypes.fetchGitHubDataAsync())
             .then(() => {
                 expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
   })
})
```

actions js file

```js
export const fetchGitHubDataAsync = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript', {
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
            }
          })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {console.log('json', json.items.slice(0, 5)); 
            return dispatch({type: 'FETCH_GITHUB_DATA', payload: json.items.slice(0, 5)})});
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use promises in your `fetchGitHubDataAsync` action?

Comment: Can you show the code of `actionTypes.fetchGitHubDataAsync()` ?

Comment: Yes, I have a fetch that returns an array of objects.

Comment: Can you log `store.dispatch(actionTypes.fetchGitHubDataAsync())` to see what you have ? is your store well initialized, like, does it work with other tests ?

Comment: It logs out undefined. The store is well initialized because redux sends data to it.

Comment: Your mock does not have items, i suspect `json.items.slice(0, 5)` will throw an error. Can you try adding items to your mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an unit test working example without using third-party mock library.

`action.js`:

```js
export const fetchGitHubDataAsync = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript', {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log('json', json.items.slice(0, 5));
        return dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_GITHUB_DATA', payload: json.items.slice(0, 5) });
      });
  };
};
```

`action.spec.js`:

```js
import * as actionTypes from './action';
import createMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const mws = [thunk];
const mockStore = createMockStore(mws);
const store = mockStore({});

describe('fetchGitHubDataAsync', () => {
  it('Dispatches BOOKS_SUCCESS after fetching books', () => {
    expect.assertions(2);
    const mJson = { items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] };
    const mResponse = { json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mJson) };
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mResponse);
    const expectedActions = [{ type: 'FETCH_GITHUB_DATA', payload: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }];
    return store.dispatch(actionTypes.fetchGitHubDataAsync()).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
      expect(global.fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript', {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58803026/action.spec.js
  fetchGitHubDataAsync
    ✓ Dispatches BOOKS_SUCCESS after fetching books (16ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58803026/action.js:239
    json [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 action.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.329s, estimated 15s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58803026

Comment: It's giving me the exact same error. My actionTypes.fetchGitHubDataAsync() returns [Function] and my expect.assertions(2) returns zero assertion calls.

Comment: @Gim-CojocaruRaul-Cristian Do you `return fetch(...)`

Comment: @Gim-CojocaruRaul-Cristian Great!